# How can I use an expression in my where clause to return a dynamic date range for my query

Tags: oracle, ssrs-2008-r2, bids

I am working in BIDS 2008r2 on a SSRS report that pulls data from an Oracle database.

I have a `where` clause that uses a hard date range, I want to change it to an expression that will dynamically change as time progresses.

This is the where clause that currently works to return the 1st day of the previous month to the last day of the previous month. ie I am looking for all data from the previous month

```
WHERE  CHRGDTTM BETWEEN {ts '2015-12-01 00:00:00'} AND {ts '2015-12-31 23:59:00'}
```

I have written an expression that returns the beginning of last month:

```
DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, DateSerial(Year(Date.Now), Month(Date.Now), 1))
```

and one that returns the end of last month:

```
DateAdd(DateInterval.Minute, -1, DateSerial(Year(Date.Now), Month(Date.Now), 1))
```

How do I get those into my `where` clause?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this entirely within the Oracle where clause you can do:

```
WHERE CHRGDTTM >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM'), -1)
AND CHRGDTTM < TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM')
```

The [`TRUNC(date)` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions220.htm) truncates the supplied date - the system date in this case; by default it removes the time part so gives you midnight this morning, but this modified that behaviour with the `MM` format model, and gives you midnight on the first of the current month. So today `TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')` gives you 2016-01-26 00:00:00. You can use that as it is for the upper end of your date range.

The [`ADD_MONTHS()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions011.htm), well, adds a number of months, -1 here to give you 2015-12-01 00:00:00 instead. Put together that gives you everything from 2015-12-01 00:00:00 up to, but no including, 2016-01-01 00:00:00, which is equivalent to your BETWEEN range.

You could also use an interval calculation to get the start of the previous month:

```
WHERE CHRGDTTM >= TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM') - INTERVAL '1' MONTH
AND CHRGDTTM < TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM')
```

which has the same effect, and is safe as you're always going to end up with a valid date from the calculation; dates at the ends of months can be more problematic.

You can read more about [datetime/interval arithmetic in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00208).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can create two parameters of type Date/Time and set the Default Values for the parameters with the expressions you've developed. Then in the query it just becomes `WHERE  CHRGDTTM BETWEEN :StartDate AND :EndDate`. If the user needn't worry about this, set the visibility to Hidden for both.